# Overlap Issue with div in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to rotate an image within a div using html and js. I have it working for the most part except for an overlapping issue: the image either covers up everything or overlaps during rotation. I thought I had resolved it with my js formula which sets the div size based on the image size, however it's not working and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
        <style>
            #photoimg {
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            }
            #photo {
            position: relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="url" name="imglink" id="imglink"  placeholder="Insert image URL here" /><br>
        <input type="button" value="Show Image" id="btn1"/>
        </form>
            <div id="photo"></div>
            <script>
                document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img id="photoimg" src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image"/>';
                    //Get larger edge
                    var largerPhotoDimension = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetWidth , 2) + Math.pow(document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetHeight ,2) );
                    //Adjust container to fix image roted 90deg
                    document.getElementById('photo').offsetWidth(largerPhotoDimension);
                    document.getElementById('photo').offsetHeight(largerPhotoDimension);     
                });
            </script>
            <button id="button">rotate</button>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
                var curr_value = document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform;
                var new_value = "rotate(90deg)";
                if(curr_value !== ""){
                    var new_rotate = parseInt(curr_value.replace("rotate(","").replace(")","")) + 90;
                    new_value = "rotate(" + new_rotate + "deg)";
                }
                document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform = new_value;
            };
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it happen when you use an image that does not have equal sides? If that is the case, then i would suggest setting a new width and height of the picture div when the image is rotated.

Comment: I made a quick codepen for you, seems to work fine in my browser (image rotates inside its own div)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKzaO .  I did use a square image though

Comment: @Burrito - Try a rectangular image. It still works, but I believe that is the issue he is facing.

Comment: @CommonKnowledge even with a rectangular image it is rotating fine, although the image is skewed due to the bounds of the div.

Comment: It does not seem to work with larger images. They still overlap or get cut off. I thought I had it set for the div to be the size of the image's diagonal rotation length but it doesn't seem to be working and idk why.

Comment: @Stevo what size image are you using?

Comment: the image i am using is = http://tinyurl.com/obbe6ue

Comment: @CommonKnowledge is correct, I think I am now seeing the issue you are seeing.  Once you rotate the image, swap the width and height of the img tag and that should fix your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these two lines

```
    document.getElementById('photoimg').style.height = document.getElementById("photo").offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById('photoimg').style.width = document.getElementById('photo').offsetHeight;
```

below

```
    document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform = new_value;
```

Comment: @Stevo looks as though you got it. I should have just posted the answer instead of a comment, durn. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys. I fixed the issue using the following code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #photoimg {
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
            #photo {
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="url" name="imglink" id="imglink"  placeholder="Insert image URL here" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Show Image" id="btn1"/>
    </form>
        <div id="photo"></div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
                document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img id="photoimg" src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image"/>';
                //Get larger edge
                var largerPhotoDimension = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetWidth , 2) + Math.pow(document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetHeight ,2) );
                var marginVert = (largerPhotoDimension - document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetHeight)/2;
                var marginHorz = (largerPhotoDimension - document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetWidth)/2;
                //Adjust container to fix image rotated 90deg
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginRight =  marginHorz;
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginLeft =  marginHorz;
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginBottom = marginVert;  
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginTop = marginVert;                  
            });
        </script>
        <button id="button">rotate</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
            var curr_value = document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform;
            var new_value = "rotate(45deg)";
            if(curr_value !== ""){
                var new_rotate = parseInt(curr_value.replace("rotate(","").replace(")","")) + 45;
                new_value = "rotate(" + new_rotate + "deg)";
            }
            document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform = new_value;
        };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```